# unsure about this code, has code smell!

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This code is bugging me,

I created a separate object EventDistance but i think its probably not needed, its just that im not sure how to code it differently.  Distance is a property i have added to a partial class for Event. Basically I want to return all events and ordered by distance.

Im thinking the extra round of foreach is perhaps unecessary.

```
public IQueryable<Event> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
        {

            var eventsList = from ev in GetAllEvents()
                             join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                             on ev.ID equals i.ID
                             select new EventDistance() { TheEvent = ev, Distance = i.Distance };


            foreach (var item in eventsList)
            {
                item.TheEvent.Distance = item.Distance;  
            }
            return eventsList.OrderBy(e => e.Distance).Select(e => e.TheEvent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need the `EventDistance` class, from what I can see.  Simply omit it, and use an anonymous type by not specifying any type in your LINQ expression:

```
public IQueryable<Event> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
    {

        var eventsList = from ev in GetAllEvents()
                         join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                         on ev.ID equals i.ID
                         select new { TheEvent = ev, Distance = i.Distance };


        foreach (var item in eventsList)
        {
            item.TheEvent.Distance = item.Distance;  
        }
        return eventsList.OrderBy(e => e.Distance).Select(e => e.TheEvent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm clueless with that LINQ syntax, but it really ought to be possible to populate the distance value in the first `select`. Something like

```
var eventsList = from ev in GetAllEvents()
                 join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                 on ev.ID equals i.ID
                 orderby i.Distance
                 select (ev => { ev.Distance = i.Distance; return ev; });
```

? Or, written properly :-)

```
var eventsList = GetAllEvents()
                 .Join(db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude),
                       ev => ev.ID,
                       i => i.ID,
                       (ev, i) => { ev.Distance = i.Distance; return ev; })
                 .OrderBy(ev => ev.Distance);
```

---

N.B. as qstarin comments below this will only be possible if we're acting on objects at this point, not ORM objects that are evalulated as SQL. That said, you can probably still

1. do the orderby in the initial fetch
2. force the objects into memory (I forget the best way to do this)
3. use a single select to combine the objects into the Event object as above rather than a loop

Comment: This probably will not work if the LINQ expression is handled by a provider that attempts to translate it into SQL.  If it occurs against in-memory objects, it should work.

Comment: re #2, Inserting a .ToList() before the selection/projection (or wherever needed) will force evaluation of the IQueryable and load the DB objects.

Comment: @qstarin Yes, that's usually how I do it but I half expect there to be a better trick. That all said, I'm now thinking we ought to talk him out of throwing away his temp object so that we do no read-into-memory in this function after all. Oh well.

Comment: I often ponder how LINQ providers could be smarter about what gets translated into SQL and being able to split those operations from ones that need to be performed against objects.  I'm not aware of any LINQ providers that do that, but it sure would be nice not to have to sprinkle .ToList()'s here and there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it as an IQueryable, you can do this:

```
        public IQueryable<Event> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
        {

            return from ev in GetAllEvents()
                   join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                   on ev.ID equals i.ID
                   order by i.Distance
                   select ev;
        }
```

As long as the GetAllEvents() method return IQueryable too that is.

EDIT: I have now actually tried out Rup's suggestion below, and you should be able to return an IQueryable without invoking the db call in this method. Like this:

```
        public IQueryable<EventDistance> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
        {
                return from ev in GetAllEvents()
                   join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                   on ev.ID equals i.ID
                   orderby i.Distance
                   select new EventDistance
                   {
                       Event = ev,
                       Distance = i.Distance
                   };
       }
```

The EventDistance class does not need to be mapped.

Comment: But then you've lost the i.Distance property - in his example he stores that into the event object to return.

Comment: I'm starting to think the best answer would be to modify your method to `select new EventDistance() { TheEvent = ev, Distance = i.Distance }` and return an `IQueryable<EventDistance>` - would that work? I'm suspicious it wouldn't since it's not an object the data layer knows about - although it is something it has a recipe for mapping into. I'm now properly confused.

Comment: I was actually just thinking the same thing, but it's so long time since I used LINQ for data-access, so I honestly don't know if it will :) ... But I just fired up VS to try it out. I'll be back.

Comment: It works! It returns an IQueryable<EventDistance> without touching the db.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
public IQueryable<Event> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude)
    {

        var eventsList = from ev in GetAllEvents()
                         join i in db.NearestEvents(latitude, longitude)
                         on ev.ID equals i.ID
                         select new Event { ID = ev.ID, Distance = i.Distance };


        return eventsList.OrderBy(e => e.Distance).AsQueryable();
    }
```